# How to add attributes to changed background-image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an application. One of the features of the application is a custom background setter. I have a script that sets the background via URL on a function. That all functions perfectly. But the problem is that I want to add the background-image attributes `background-size` and `background-repeat` so any size works and makes sense.

This is the code to what I have working so far.

```
<a href="#" onclick="funcBgImage()">
    <img src="example.com/example-image-url.png" height=50, width=50></img>
</a>

<script>
function funcBgImage() {
    var imageurl = prompt("Enter Image URL","");
    if (imageurl != null) { 
        document.body.style.background = "url('" + imageurl + "')"
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried merely adding `; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;` after `"url('" + imageurl + "')` but now it won't set *any* backgrounds.

I'd expect it to work, but it doesn't. Can anyone explain why, and how to correctly do this?

Comment: Use a new line for each style - `document.body.style.x = y;`. Or, after setting the new image, *select the image first*, then apply the styles to it. Don't forget the semicolon at the end of the url statement.

Comment: I guess, you don't have to select the image, continue to use `body`. Edit: I just tried with the prompt and it doesn't work. Sry, check back.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working, the `background-image` is updated with a prompt from the user every 5 seconds.

```js
function setBackground() {
  let val = prompt("Please insert a positive integer:");
  while(isNaN(parseInt(val)) && parseInt(val) > -1 && parseInt(val) < 1000) {
    val = prompt("Please insert a positive integer:");
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("https://picsum.photos/id/${val}/128")`;
}

setBackground();
setInterval(() => {
  setBackground();
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

only the line where you define the style al body that:

this is url test: stick it in the field

https://as.com/meristation/imagenes/2019/06/10/betech/1560195710_365328_1560195771_noticia_normal.jpg

```js
function funcBgImage() {
    var imageurl = prompt("Enter Image URL","");
    if (imageurl != null) { 

        document.body.style =  "background-image: url('" + imageurl + "'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; "
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="funcBgImage()">
    <img src=""
    
    id="imgStyleAttr" height=50, width=50></img>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate in 2 lines:

```
var imageurl = prompt("Enter Image URL", "");
if (imageurl != null) {
    document.body.style.background = "url('" + imageurl + "') no-repeat"; // no-repeat here.
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover"; // cover in a separate line.
}
```

There might be a browser issue, not sure. I used FF.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Do you have any info on why what I did didn't work by chance? I don't want to repeat that mistake again in a different scenario.

Comment: I think it's browser support, only for `background-size`.